# Java: Storing random seed for reproducing with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, random

For a simulation that I am running I am using the Java Random object a lot. Because I want to be able to reproduce my results when something interesting occurs I save the random seed like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
Long seed = r.nextLong();
Random rand = new Random(seed);
```

This way I can save the seed and re run the simulation with the same seed. The problem is however that I am also using threads: in simulation 1 thread 'a' may invoke rand.nextInt() first and thread 'b' second and in simulation 2 thread 'b' may invoke rand.nextInt() first. Could I manage the threads in such a way that the threads always invoke a piece of code in the same sequence? And if so, wouldn't that make the threads redundant?

I thought about invoking rand.nextInt() before creation of each thread and then passing it as an argument, but this does not work in my case: I also use Collections.shuffle(List list, Random rand) and you can pass a Random object as argument but not the int itself already.

Comment: It is common practice to use the current timestamp as a seed. You can save this value for later use if you need to reproduce the pseudorandom sequence.

Comment: You can assign separate `Random` instances for each thread, each with a provided seed generated from the core seed. Consider using `SplittableRandom`, which is meant for this type of parallelization.

Comment: There's a class just for this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html

Answer (score 0):

Each thread should have its own `Random` object rather than sharing one between all the threads. You can either pass it as a parameter or create them inside each thread.

On a side note, it is common practice to use the current timestamp as a seed. You can save this value for later use if you need to reproduce the pseudorandom sequence.

Comment: Thank you, did not know about using the current timestamp! Will do that in the future. Should I then save all seeds of the Random objects of the threads to reproduce? Was kind of hoping that it was possible with saving one seed.

Comment: @Fringo Check out the other comments to your question, especially the link for ThreadLocalRandom.